# Querying Relations Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have an issue understanding pretty well the Relationships, let's go to the point

I have 3 tables, with its proper models

> ```
> receipt
>  - id
>  - date
>
> items_sold
>  - id
>  - receipt_id
>  - item_id
>
> items
>  - id
>  - name
> ```

The problem I have is that receipt "has many" items through items_sold, but I can't use "hasManyThrough" because eloquent use the wrong "id" of "items_sold", even if I put manually the keys

```
class Receipt extends Eloquent {

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Items', 'ItemsSold', 'receipt_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

There is no way to do it in through this way, but I can find an Relationship method with eloquent that can help me with this case

Comment: select `items`.*, `items_sold`.`receipt_id` from `items` inner join `items_sold` on "`items_sold`.`id` = `items`.`id`" where `items_sold`.`receipt_id` = 1

This is the statement that eloquent make, everithing is right except this part "`items_sold`.`id` = `items`.`id`" should be "`items_sold`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lukasgeiter stated, a `belongsToMany()` relationship added to your models would allow you to access the related data.

Something else to note, if you change your join table's name to `item_reciept` you can define the many to many relationship in your models without having to specify the join table specifically. When Laravel sees a `belongsToMany` method without a join table name specified, it looks for the name of the two models involved in snake case and alphabetical order with lower case names.

Your model methods would be:

```
class Receipt extends Eloquent{

    public function items(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Item');
    }
}

class Item extends Eloquent{

    public function reciepts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Reciept');
    }
}
```

I can understand if you wouldn't want to rename your `items_sold` table because it's specific name denotes it's usage past just a join table.

Another thing to note about adding these relationships to the model is that it allows your to perform [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) with your requests which could be helpful in your situations.

Let's say you wanted to get all items for a specific receipt by it's id all in one go. You could use the following request to get everything together:

```
$receiptAndItems = Receipt::with('items')->find($recieptId);
```

This would return both the details on your particular Receipt record AND a key `items` with all of the related Item records for that given receipt:

```
// Your `receipt` record
// this is the output when you add `->toArray()` at the end to make it a bit easier to read

array (size=7)
  'id' => int 2
  'name' => string 'Foo' (length=12)
  'created_at' => string '2014-11-22 16:30:02' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2014-11-22 16:30:02' (length=19)
  'items' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 1
          'name' => string 'Bar' (length=13)
          'created_at' => string '2014-11-22 16:30:02' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2014-11-22 16:30:02' (length=19)
          'pivot' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      1 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 2
          'name' => string 'Baz' (length=20)
          'created_at' => string '2014-11-22 16:30:02' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2014-11-22 16:30:02' (length=19)
          'pivot' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      2 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 3
          'name' => string 'FooBarBaz' (length=18)
          'created_at' => string '2014-11-22 16:30:02' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2014-11-22 16:30:02' (length=19)
          'pivot' => 
            array (size=2)
```

Comment: No problem. I didn't want to snake your check, but I just went through figuring a lot of this out with my current project so I wanted to pay it forward :)

Comment: No worries. I'm sure somebody someday will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you actually need is a **many-to-many** relationship found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

```
public function items(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Items', 'items_sold');
}
```

*Is you model really called "Items"? If it's actually "Item", change to first parameter in the above code accordingly*

Comment: Its real name is another hehe, I made a mistake but it would be as you say "Item", I going to run some test, thank you.

Comment: well, your right, thank you, I need laravel manual for dummies xD