# Best way to apply Eloquent's ORM with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have two tables:

```
treatments (
id,
name
)

companies (
id,
name
)
```

And I need to build a relation to a "price" table. I thougth in something like follows:

```
prices (
treatment_id,
company_id,
price
)
```

But i don know how to apply the ORM to a php aplication. I'm using Laravel with Eloguent's ORM. I think that the real question would be if this is a good way to design the db. Perhaps I should make it diferent?
Any advices?
Thanks,
Ban.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying Relations Laravel Eloquent ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090544/querying-relations-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Comment: Hey Ban, you should take a look at this answer for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090544/querying-relations-laravel-eloquent-orm/27091636#27091636

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Company can have multiple Treatments and a treatment can be bought from multiple companies at different prices, then you have a [Many-to-many](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/table-relationships/) relationship, with `prices` being the pivot table (which if you would adhere to convention would be named `company_treament`, but that's not a must). So you'll need to have two models for `Treatments` and `Companies`, which would look like this:

```
class Company extends \Eloquent {
    
    public function treatments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Treatment', 'prices')->withPivot('price');
    }
```

and

```
class Treatment extends \Eloquent {
    
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Company', 'prices')->withPivot('price');
    }
}
```

The `treatments()` and `companies()` methods from the models are responsible for fetching the related items. Usually the `hasMany` method only requires the related model as the first parameter, but in your case the pivot table name is non-standard and is set to `prices` by passing it as the second parameter. Also normally for the pivot table only the relation columns  would be fetched (`treatment_id` and `company_id`) so you need to specify the the extra column using `withPivot`. So if you want to get the treatments for a company with the id 1 list you whould to something like this:

```
$treatments = Company::find(1)->treatments;
```

The opposite is also true:

```
$companies = Treatment::find(1)->companies;
```

If you need to access the price for any of those relations you can do it like this:

```
foreach ($treatments as $treatment)
{
    $price = $treatment->pivot->price;
}
```

You can read more about how to implement relationships using Eloquent in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many).

#### EDIT

To insert a relation entry in the pivot table you can use `attach` and to remove one use `detach` (for more info read the [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)).

```
$treatment->companies()->attach($companyId, array('price' => $price));
$treatment->companies()->detach($companyId);
```

To update a pivot table entry use `updateExistingPivot`:

```
$treatment->companies()->updateExistingPivot($companyId, array('price' => $price));
```

Comment: I read that I should use BelongsToMany instead hasMany because it is a manytomany relation and not a onetomany. I'm wrong?

Comment: How could I insert the price to a treatment? I need to save the following information: treatment_1 costs 50€ if the patient belongs to company_1. I tried somtehing like this but did.t worked...

`$treatment = new Treatment;   
$treatment->name = "treatment_1";   
$treatment->company('24')->price= 24.14;  
$treatment->save();  `

Comment: Yes you're right about `belongsToMany`, my mistake, I've corrected the answer. I've also updated it with the relevant info for working with pivot tables.

Comment: Thank you Bogdan! You helped me a lot!!